# SQL delete query with foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I know that this question belongs to the very early stages of the database theory, but I have not encountered such a problem since several months. If someone has a database with some tables associated together as "chain" with foreign keys and they want to delete a record from a table which has some "dependent" tables, what obstacles arise? In particular, in a database with tables: Person, Profile, Preference, Filter exist the associations as `Person.id` is foreign key in `Profile` and `Profile.id` is foreign key in `Preference` and `Filter.id` is foreign key in `Preference`, so as that all the associations`enter code here` are `OneToMany`. Is it possible to delete a Person with a simple query:

```
Delete from Person p where p.id= 34;
```

If no, how should look like the query in order to perform the delete successfully? 
If the database in the application is managed by hibernate, what constraints (`annotations`) should I apply to the associated fields of each entity, so as to be able with the above simple query to perform the delete?

Comment: If the Profile and Preference tables have a foreign key constraint against a PersonId record and you attempt to delete the person id from the Person table it will violate the constraint. You would need to either delete on cascade or remove the person id from each table where the constraint applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOR SQL VERSION

[image]

Look at the Screenshot. you can use the Insert Update Specificaiton Rules. as it has Delete and Update Rules. you can set either of these values.

Foreign key constraints may be created by referencing a primary or unique key. Foreign key constraints ensure the relational integrity of data in associated tables. A foreign key value may be NULL and indicates a particular record has no parent record. But if a value exists, then it is bound to have an associated value in a parent table. When applying update or delete operations on parent tables there may be different requirements about the effect on associated values in child tables. There are four available options in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 as follows:

```
No Action
Cascade
SET NULL
SET Default
```

Use this article for Refrence.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/

ORACLE VERSION

you can use one of below.

alter table sample1
   add foreign key (col1)
references
   sample (col2)
on delete no action;

alter table sample1
add foreign key (col1)
references
   sample (col2)
on delete restrict;

alter table sample1
add foreign key (col1)
   references sample (col2)
on delete cascade;

for refrance.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

Comment: This question is tagged `Oracle`.

Comment: @Jodha - the SQL tag stands for the language, not for a particular RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

answer is no if there is foreign key constraint then you have to delete leaf node table data first

that is first delete from `Preference` table

then from `Profile and Filter` Table

then delete record from `Person table`

This is the generic concept that you apply anywhere